# Segmentation Fault-PollFd

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, client, server

I have a pollfd structure and I initialise every element with the file descriptor of every client.
I have to implement the Pheasant game so every time a client mistakes,he is removed from the array.
The game works but when I remain with the last client,I receive the "Segmentation fault" error and the server closes and the server doesn`t write the  message to the client.

Comment: You should post code here to make it possible to answer.

Comment: A debugger will help you considerably. But check that you have the correct no of arguments for your format, then check that the format specifiers match type with the arguments and finally, if there are any pointers to things (strings for example) check that they are not NULL and point to where you think they do. I know that most modern compilers do a lot of the basic checking for you, but they can be fooled or misdirected by bugs in the code running up to the printf.